# Jenkins scripted pipeline - branch conditionals with wildcards

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I get something similar to declarative pipeline "when branch is equal to any of those..." in  scripted pipeline, including possible wildcards?

For example in declarative pipeline I have:

```
when { 
      anyOf{
            branch "master";
            branch "feature/*";
            branch "fix/*"
      }
}
```

How I can achieve this in scripted pipeline?
I tried something like that:

```
def branches = ["master", "feature/*", "fix/*"]
if (branches.any{branch -> branch = env.BRANCH_NAME){ 
   do something here 
}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work for wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using regular expression matching:

```
def branches = ["master", "feature/.*", "fix/.*"]
if( branches.any{ branch -> env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ branch }) {
    do something here
}
```

Here we use the `==~` operator to match the string on the left-hand side with the regular expression on the right-hand side.

Note that we don't use `=~`, because we don't want substring matches (e. g. we don't want "mymaster" to be a match for "master").

See [Groovy Goodness: Matchers for Regular Expressions](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)